# "On the other there's a set of anxieties about us having any more downtime" Is it correct?

Tags: transcription

I listened to a recording

For mp3 file from bbe.com [Start at 03:49](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/thai/features/6-minute-english/ep-21082014)

For youtube [Start at 03:47](https://youtu.be/ckDzaxXlfF0?t=226)

The transcript shows that

> On the other there's a set of anxieties about us having any more downtime.

Is that a correct sentence?

It seems to me

> On the other there's a set of anxieties about us not having any more downtime

So, what is a correct sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transcript is incorrect as she clearly states "... about us **not** having any more downtime..." as you had suggested.